# How to prevent delete confirmation in Emacs Dired?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I type d followed by x, and I am prompted to confirm yes/no. I would like it to just delete, not ask for confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```
(setq dired-deletion-confirmer '(lambda (x) t))
```